# Truncatewords by percentage of total words count

Tags: python, django

How to truncate text field by words depending on words count?

For example `{{ post.content|truncatewords_by_percents:"20%" }}`

Comment: check to see if there is a built in template tag, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/,
if there isn't you can create your own template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible without making a custom template tag. Built-in template tags allow truncation by characters or words only. See documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars).